# trying to implement simple ostream singleton class

Tags: c++, singleton, iostream

I want to implement a singleton class that receives file path as a parameter. I tried to write the following code . I know it doesn't work and not good but I can't find why..

```
class OutputData {
    std::fstream ofile;
    std::ostream iout;
    static OutputData *odata;
    OutputData(const char* path):iout(std::cout), ofile(path) {
        if (ofile.is_open()) {
            iout = ofile;
        }
    }
public:
    static void print(std::string s) {
        iout << s;
    }
};
```

in .cpp

```
OutputData *OutputData::odata = nullptr;
```

and from now on I want that every class will have the ability to write to that stream.

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use a singleton for this, instead of just providing a stream `operator<<()` overload for `OutputData` ??

Comment: because I have a dozen of classes in my project that need to use that stream

Comment: You didn't get what I was saying: Pass it as a reference instead of using a singleton, everything else unnecessarily clutters your design (especially with a big class hierarchy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't take any `std::istream` or `std::ostream` instance by copy, your member variables should be references or pointers:

```
class OutputData {
    std::fstream* ofile;
    std::ostream* iout;
    static OutputData *odata;
    OutputData(const char* path):iout(nullptr), ofile(nullptr) {
        ofile = new fstream(path);
        if (ofile->is_open()) {
            iout = ofile;
        }
        else {
            delete ofile;
            ofile = nullptr;
            iout = &cout;
        }
    }
    // Take care to provide an appropriate destructor
    ~OutputData() {
        delete ofile;
    }

};
```

---

Also regarding your singleton design, I'd rather recommend Scott Meyer's singleton idiom:

```
class OutputData {
public:
    static OutputData& instance(const char* path) {
        static OutputData theInstance(path)
        return theInstance;
    }
    // Make print a non-static member function
    void print(std::string s) {
        iout << s;
    }
};
```

---

Though this approach just weirdly looks exactly like the opposite, as what's considered the canonical solution.

Comment: and how do I initiate it let's say with an argv from the main?

Comment: @itorra I seriously doubt, you really want a singleton.

Comment: why wouldn't I ? what is another classic solution instead of start passing OutputData object all over the project?

Comment: @itorra _" ... start passing OutputData object all over the project?"_ Yes indeed, that's considered the better solution. Pass it as a parameter (maybe by means of an interface). Nevertheless I gave you a viable solution in my answer, if you're sure you want to stick to `Singleton`.

Comment: I get it and will use it with << operator. thank you!